# Movie with the same weapon as in "The Rock"

Tags: identify-this-movie

What is the name of the movie which uses the same "VX Poison Gas Pearls" as a weapon that "The Rock" used. Maybe they have another name in the movie, but it was the same prop that was used in "The Rock".

The movie is very similar to "The Rock" in that they use the Pearls as a threat to extort money from some country.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krCYn.jpg]

The Film starts with a research project of  the  government,  that crashes and destroys a little island.

Years later a terrorist group steals this bio weapon and threatens, on live TV, to throw the glass pearls over a bridge (that would destroy a city near the bridge) if they don't get a ransom.

But, the main actor attacks them and steals the bio weapon and tries to flee.  During the escape, he was stopped in a tunnel and now had a new problem: the bio weapon would explode if it heats up over 20°C.

Then the army decides to close the tunnel with skyrockets.  Now the main actor tries to save the people in the tunnel. He finds ice in a cargo bay (which was to be used for cooling beer).

Nobody was killed, a happy ending.

This is what I can remember so far from my memories... but I don't remember the title or any of the actors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, most part, especially the tunnel part, sounds exactly like [*The Chill Factor*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0163579/).

I don't think there is any TV threatening, the evil guys just want to sell the weapon. It is one of the researchers who smuggles it out and by accident it gets into the hands of two average guys who are then chased by the evil guys in an attempt to get the weapon. This weapon has indeed some similarities to the VX gas. It is in a form of small gelatinous pearls, which always have to be kept cold.

There is also a bridge scene, where there is a small standoff, and one party (the good ones, I think) pretends to throw it over the bridge (or was it a dam, maybe even Hoover Damn, considering mid-western scenery?), so that the others don't get it. But at the end there is exactly this tunnel scene you describe. So I'm pretty sure you're after this movie but imported some memories from *The Rock*, like the terroristic threatening and the glass pearls (which are a bit different here, being a gelatinous mass).

**EDIT:** And Wikipedia says, it also begins with an island research facility getting accidentally devastated by the weapon, though I didn't remember this myself.

Comment: Well that is the movie, I was searching for. Thank you so much!